# Return matched array items and remove them from original array

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to find whether `lodash` has a function where I can filter based on some query, return an array of the matched objects, but remove the matched objects from the original array.

So very similar to `_.filter`, but where the original array is modified with the matched elements removed.

**Example**

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(originalArray);
----> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

var evenNumbers = _.somethingSimilarToFilter(originalArray, function(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0
});

console.log(evenNumbers);
----> 2, 4

console.log(originalArray);
----> 1, 3, 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done it using native JavaScript **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** methods

```js
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var evenNumbers = originalArray.filter(function(n, i, arr) {
  // just remove the element from array if  even number
  return n % 2 === 0 && arr.splice(i, 1)
});

console.log(originalArray, evenNumbers);
```